# How to return the next element from a spliterator in java

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, consumer, spliterator

I want to get the next element from a spliterator, not just "perform action" on the next element. For example by implementing the following method

```
<T> T getnext(Spliterator<T> s) {

}
```

All search results I found just said that tryAdvance() was like a combination of an iterators hasNext() and next(), except that is a BIG LIE because I can't get next element, just "perform action on next element".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the item in a list and then return from that list:

```java
    public static <T> T getNext(Spliterator<T> spliterator) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(1);

        if (spliterator.tryAdvance(result::add)) {
            return result.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

To make it more obvious to the caller that this is an operation that may return null, consider returning `Optional`:

```java
    public static <T> Optional<T> getNext(Spliterator<T> spliterator) {
        final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(1);

        if (spliterator.tryAdvance(result::add)) {
            return Optional.of(result.get(0));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to return an `Optional`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820895/2711488) is simpler. Your first variant can be simplified to `return spliterator.tryAdvance(result::add)? result.get(0): null;` Or you use `Deque<T> d = new ArrayDeque<>(1); spliterator.tryAdvance(d::push); return d.poll();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct way but you can use :

```
<T> T getnext(Spliterator<T> s) {
    Stream<T> stream = StreamSupport.stream(s, false); // convert Spliterator to stream
    Iterable<T> iterable = stream::iterator; // then stream to Iterable
    return iterable.iterator().next(); // then you can get next element
 }
```

Or in one step like so :

```
 return StreamSupport.stream(s, false).iterator().next();
```

Or more simpler :

```
 return Spliterators.iterator(s).next();
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the right approach: too many steps (spliterator -> stream -> iterator)

Comment: and it could be simplified to `return StreamSupport.stream(s, false).iterator().next();`

Comment: @Andrew I agree but there are no direct way

Comment: Even simpler with [`return Spliterators.iterator(s).next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#iterator-java.util.Spliterator-)…

Answer (score 1):

transform spliterator to stream

```
<T> Optional<T> getnext(Spliterator<T> s) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(s, false).findFirst();
}
```

example

```
List<String> lst = List.of("a", "b");
Spliterator<String> spliterator = lst.spliterator();

System.out.println(getnext(spliterator)); //Optional[a]
System.out.println(getnext(spliterator)); //Optional[b]
```